# How to make python3.2 interpreter the default interpreter in debian

Tags: python, linux, debian

I got both python2 and python3 installed in my debian machine. But when i try to invoke the python interpreter by just typing 'python' in bash, python2 pops up and not python3. Since I am working with the latter at the moment, It would be easier to invoke python3 by just typing python. Please guide me through this.

Comment: This is a **very** bad idea since it might break system tools that depend on Python 2.x.

Comment: Agree with Larsmans...why not just run it with `python3` its just an extra letter and then you can keep both versions easily accessible in case you need version2.

Comment: If typing `python` is easier than typing `python3` than using an alias (`alias py3="python3"`) would make it even easier!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the only somehow safe way would be to use an alias in your shell, by placing

```
alias python=python3
```

into your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`...

this way the system scripts depending on python being python2 won't be affected.

Comment: What about the rest of tools, such as ipython?

Comment: Of course you can also add an alias for them if you want to start `ipython3` using `ipython`. It's just that you shouldn't have a `python` binary (or symlink) in your path that points to `python3`, as scipts will expect `python` being `python2`. I for my part have simply gotten used to type python3...

Answer (score 9):

Well, you can simply create a `virtualenv` with the python3.x using this command:

`virtualenv -p <path-to-python3.x> <virtualenvname>`

Answer (score 5):

btw, if you are using bash or running from the shell,
and you normally include at the top of the file the following line:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

then you can change the line to instead be:

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

That is another way to have python*X* run instead of the default 
(where *X* is 2 or 3).

Answer (score 1):

Others have adviced you about the possible drawbacks, so, on the issue at hand:

```
ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score -4):

using command:

```
    update-alternatives --config python
```

Might Work However On My System(I have Python2&3 Installed As Well) It Gives Me An Error Saying No Alternatives For Python...

Comment: Even of it worked, it would be a bad idea; but it doesn't, pretty much exactly for that reason.

Comment: python3 is not an alternative to python2