# Installing Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So I'm trying to download requests using pip and am getting the error below. I've checked the error log but it's largely incomprehensible to me.

Any suggestions? I'm getting a similar issue when trying to use pip for beautifulsoup4.

```
~ ∴ pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (625kB): 625kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1380, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 664, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 894, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 202, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 189, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/my_name/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: Not sure if you are installing it as a virtual environment or just plainly on the system but perhaps try running it with the sudo command for elevated privileges as in: sudo pip install requests

Answer (score 15):

You are trying to install the package in '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests' but it requires  root permissions to do so. This should do the trick:

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: ah i see, so why is this installing within python 2.7.  i have python 3 installed...

Comment: Try running ``python -c "import sys; print (sys.version)"``. In your bash shell, type "python" and press <TAB>. It will list all the different versions of your python installed. Chances are that Python 3 is available as "python3". You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434260/how-to-make-python3-2-interpreter-the-default-interpreter-in-debian if you wish to change the default.

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
pip install --user requests
```

(that's as it's written, you don't have to substitute anything in)

Answer (score 3):

This is the important part:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'
```

To install a library system-wide(in that folder) you need root privileges, use sudo:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Alternatively take a look at [virtualenv](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/) so that you can have different local installations without needing root.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X :

First install pip by this command :

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then install requests by this command :

```
pip install --user requests
```

Answer (score 1):

If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

```
sudo -H pip install --user requests
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Pycharm, trying to update your requests from 2.5 to 2.7, you will get the same error, I typed the following into my command line:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade requests
```

if it asks for your password, just enter the password for your computer

and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

all done!!